# XML to JSON using Ruby and save it for separate file

Tags: ruby, json, xml-parsing

I newbie Ruby programmer and just got new assignment to convert huge XML and save it to separate JSON file. So for example:

```
<listing>
  <id>abc12345</id>
  <name>BCD</name>
  <address>12 Main St</address>
</listing>

<listing>
  <id>a1b2c3d4</id>
  <name>XYZ</name>
  <address>14 Main St</address>
</listing>

<listing>
  <id>bcde45678</id>
  <name>MNO</name>
  <address>14 Broadway</address>
</listing>
```

I want to save it to individual file and using id as the filename on this example would be abc12345.json, a1b2c3d4.json, and bcde45678.json with each will contain something like this:

```
    {
  "listing": {
    "id": "bcde45678",
    "name": "MNO",
    "address": "14 Broadway"
  }
}
```

Is anyone can help me out on this problem. For all future help I really appreciated

Comment: what are those files `abc12345.json, a1b2c3d4.json, and bcde45678.json` would contain?

Comment: What code have you written to solve this? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: I update it the content of the file that I want to save. I am Ruby programmer so I think I will use Ruby

Comment: Define "huge XML". Huge measured in kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes, terabytes? If you're looking at tens or hundreds of megabytes on up, don't "slurp" the incoming XML. That's not scalable, so, instead, use line-by-line I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to print the listing blocks to individual files as JSON. If you have access to 'active_support/core_ext' and 'nokogiri', and you aren't too concerned about how your XML is converted to JSON, you can just do:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'nokogiri'

xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.read "yourfile")

xml.search("//listing").each do |l|
  filename = l.at_xpath("id").content
  File.open(filename + '.json', 'w') do |file|
    file.print Hash.from_xml(l.to_xml).to_json
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't have rails installed, still can I do `require 'active_support/core_ext'` ?

Comment: Yes, but you will probably have to `gem install activesupport` first. (Note that there is no underscore in the gem name.)

Comment: I tried but it only create first file and stop to continue the next one. But Thank you for the respond @kardeiz

Comment: Is your XML file a well-formed XML document? That is, does it [contain one and only one root node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element)? If not, then yes, you will encounter errors like that.

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks finally I got it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good case for using [XMLSimple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/) (or not, it's your choice of poisons) and using JSON's core module extensions:

```
require 'json/add/core'
require 'xmlsimple'

xml_files = [
'<listing>
  <id>abc12345</id>
  <name>BCD</name>
  <address>12 Main St</address>
</listing>',
'<listing>
  <id>a1b2c3d4</id>
  <name>XYZ</name>
  <address>14 Main St</address>
</listing>',
'<listing>
  <id>bcde45678</id>
  <name>MNO</name>
  <address>14 Broadway</address>
</listing>'
]

xml_files.each do |xml|
  obj = XmlSimple.xml_in(xml, :ForceArray => false)
  File.write(obj['id'] + '.json', JSON.pretty_generate(obj))
end
```

Which creates three files:

a1b2c3d4.json:

```
{
  "id": "a1b2c3d4",
  "name": "XYZ",
  "address": "14 Main St"
}
```

abc12345.json:

```
{
  "id": "abc12345",
  "name": "BCD",
  "address": "12 Main St"
}
```

bcde45678.json:

```
{
  "id": "bcde45678",
  "name": "MNO",
  "address": "14 Broadway"
}
```

I suspect XMLSimple is based on Perl's XMLSimple, which reads an XML file and converts it into native objects. In this case it'll create a hash of the XML, allowing easy access to the `<id>` tag's contents as a normal hash key. XMLSimple has, and needs, a lot of flexibility for parsing the incoming XML into an object, so I fine-tuned it using the `:ForceArray => false` flag, which gives the code some leniency when creating the values to the hash keys. You'll want to spend some time nosing through the documentation to learn it's options.

`JSON.pretty_generate(obj)` creates the nicely formatted output. That balloons the filesize, but that's OK if you have humans who have to read those files. If not, use `obj.to_json` to generate a more compact output, which will reduce the I/O time when reading the JSON files.

That takes care of writing individual chunks of the XML.

You don't say what "huge" means. In my world, huge can be multi-GB files, well into the double-digits. For a very big XML file, I'd recommend looking into using Nokogiri::SAX to use stream processing and generate small XML files, similar to your example XML. Then you can iterate over those using the code above.

If the files are not really huge, but are merely large, let Nokogiri parse the entire file into a DOM and walk over the `<listing>` nodes, and output them to files. The example XML you gave isn't valid for a real XML file because it's missing the containing node, so, based on a "fixed" version:

```
require 'json/add/core'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'xmlsimple'

xml_files =<<EOT
<xml_root>
  <listing>
    <id>abc12345</id>
    <name>BCD</name>
    <address>12 Main St</address>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <id>a1b2c3d4</id>
    <name>XYZ</name>
    <address>14 Main St</address>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <id>bcde45678</id>
    <name>MNO</name>
    <address>14 Broadway</address>
  </listing>
</xml_root>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_files)

xml_files = []
doc.search('listing').each do |listing|
  xml_file = listing.at('id').text + '.xml'
  xml_files << xml_file
  File.write(xml_file, listing.to_xml)
end

xml_files.each do |file|
  obj = XmlSimple.xml_in(File.read(file), :ForceArray => false)
  File.write(obj['id'] + '.json', JSON.pretty_generate(obj))
end
```

After running, these files exist, and the contents of the JSON files correlate to the corresponding XML file:

```
a1b2c3d4.json  a1b2c3d4.xml   abc12345.json  abc12345.xml   bcde45678.json bcde45678.xml
```

For simple XML, you can dispense with XMLSimple, but for large XML blocks the following can get to be a bit of a pain, but, at least it's a pain you can choose. This is how to do it without SimpleXML:

```
require 'json/add/core'
require 'nokogiri'

xml_files =<<EOT
<xml_root>
  <listing>
    <id>abc12345</id>
    <name>BCD</name>
    <address>12 Main St</address>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <id>a1b2c3d4</id>
    <name>XYZ</name>
    <address>14 Main St</address>
  </listing>
  <listing>
    <id>bcde45678</id>
    <name>MNO</name>
    <address>14 Broadway</address>
  </listing>
</xml_root>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml_files)

xml_files = []
doc.search('listing').each do |listing|
  id, name, address = %w[id name address].map { |node| listing.at(node).content }
  File.write(
    id + '.json',
    {
      'id'      => id,
      'name'    => name,
      'address' => address
    }.to_json
  )
end
```

Comment: Are they `'json/add/core'` and `xmlsimple` external gem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This convert XML to JSON and save separate new JSON file

```
require "rubygems"
require "crack"
require "json"

folder_path = '/xml_files/local/folder_path'

Dir.foreach(folder_path) do |xml_file|

  next if xml_file == '.' || xml_file == '..'
  myXML = Crack::XML.parse(File.read("/local/folder_path/#{xml_file}"))
  myJSON = JSON.pretty_generate(myXML)

  filename_without = xml_file.sub(".xml", "")
  
  File.open("created_json_files_local_path/#{filename_without}.json", 'w') do |f|
   f.write(myJSON)
  end

end
```